# How to display more than one "categories" in enterprise wiki page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, enterprise-wiki, categories

I have an Enterprise Wiki Page and I am looking to display more than one "Categories" field on the side bar.

Currently, the closest I have got to doing this, is by building a new Enterprise Wiki page layout, and editing the HTML codes in SharePoint Designer. I have found a snippet/section of codes for the wiki categories, and have duplicated it.

[image]

This is the full code

```
        <div>
            <!--CS: Start Page Field: Wiki Categories Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldTaxonomyFieldControl" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <!--MS:<PageFieldTaxonomyFieldControl:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="e1a5b98c-dd71-426d-acb6-e478c7a5882f" runat="server">-->
                <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Wiki Categories1</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"><div></div></div></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
            <!--ME:</PageFieldTaxonomyFieldControl:TaxonomyFieldControl>-->
            <!--CE: End Page Field: Wiki Categories Snippet-->
        </div>
```

Notice I have changed the "name" to Wiki Categories1.

Subsequently, I have loaded the new page layout, but this is what I got. The first part of the screenshot is what I have during the "edit page" mode. The second part is what I see when I save the changes.

[image]

As you can see, I literally cloned the "Categories" field. Whatever input I put into the first "wiki categories" during the "edit page" mode is copied into the second "wiki categories" when the changes are saved, even though nothing is filled in (Sorry I know in the screenshot, both "wiki" categories are filled in with the same input already). Also, there is no "Wiki Categories1" anywhere.

I believe this has something to do with the *Fieldname* code in the HTML codes.

Please assist if you have any idea how to go about this! Thanks!

Comment: This guy seems to have done it in SharePoint 2010. How can I do it for O365 SharePoint and how? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9570dfe0-d5cf-4fd6-958f-42d744340931/override-div-tag-in-wiki-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT. This solution still requires some styling, but at least I got it to work.

The key is really to know what codes to paste in, to get a new category. And this can be found in "Design Manager > Edit Page Layout > Click on the Page Layout you want to edit > Snippets (in the upper navigation bar. It's easy to miss it)"

Once you are in, select the "Content fields" you want to include under "Page fields". To insert the additional custom "Categories" field, you have to first follow the steps [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186729/how-can-i-create-a-content-field-in-page-fields-of-snippets-gallery). Then copy the codes under "HTML Snippet" and paste it into the SharePoint Designer (under page layouts, find the custom layout you created, and paste the codes in) like this:

[image]

Make sure you have added this page layout into the list of layouts that you can use under "Site Settings > Page layouts and site templates". Then you can choose this Page Layout to display when editing a page.

This is my end result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, after I have done this, I was met with another problem. Upon saving, the displayed page does not display the metatags as links for the 2 new fields that I created. The metatags were simply displayed as text and I am still trying to figure this out here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187300/metadata-managed-column-snippet-not-working-in-custom-page-layout