# How can I create a Content Field in Page Fields of Snippets Gallery?

Tags: page-layout, enterprise-wiki, snippet

Currently I am building a new page layout using an enterprise wiki setting. I have the following "Content Fields" in my choice of "Page Fields" under "Snippets Gallery" or "Design Manager".

[image]

I believe I have incidentally added "Products" and the "HashTags" option in, but I can't remember how I did it.

I have tried adding new "Columns" under "Site Columns > Create", but the new columns does not get added into the snippet options. Which leads me to believe that there must be some settings somewhere that I have to check/add to get the other columns into the "Content Fields" option.

Please assist! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out by luck.

At the "Edit Page Layouts" page, click on the "Enterprise Wiki Page". (Idk how else to navigate to the following page, anyone with an idea, please comment)
[image]

At the following page, click on "Add from existing site columns" (this is assuming that you have already created the custom columns) and it will then launch you to this page, where you can select the columns to be included.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Setting --> Design Manager --> Choose Edit Page Layouts(from the left
  side navigation)
- Choose your desired Associated Content types linked with your Page Layout.
- Click Add on existing content types
- Select the column
- You can see the added column under Page Field in the Snippet Gallery

[image]